# Using now or block.timestamp

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-debugging

If using 'now' or 'block.timestamp' is considering security risks (miner manipulation) how should I go about current timestamp in my code? Isn't it safe to use either of the two as long as it is not used for randomness?

Comment: What is the use case for the timestamp? It's guaranteed to be roughly accurate, on the order of hours, but certainly don't use it for precise timings

Comment: For example in an ICO, where you would want to check and adjust bonuses based on specifc timestamps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are not basing some critical/time-sensitive logic on block.timestamp you should be ok.

For an ICO that adjusts the bonuses on different timestamps, it shouldn't be a problem. The worst case scenario would be someone investing a few hours after some deadline getting the bonus of the previous tier.

Using now / block.timestamp is a concern when the logic is based on perfectly timing an action.

Comment: One could manipulate the `block.timestamp` to get all bonuses earlier than at a right time. Why do you think this is not a concern? Like in the tip model when user is allowed to withdraw money only in tranches.